# Calculating the size of an object using opencv and numpy poly1d

Tags: numpy, opencv, curve-fitting

I'm looking to use a small numpy array to generate a curve that I can use to predict the height measurement at non-known points. I have several points that I am using to create a poly1d. I know it's possible, we use software that does it just fine at work, and when I used a different image as a tester, plugging the values into Excel and getting the polynomial, it worked fine, but I'm getting pretty drastic measurements on a different calibratable image, I get drastically different results.

Here is the image that I'm trying to measure. [image: I work in utility pole engineering]

The stick on the front of the pole contains known measurements. From bottom to top, they are 3'6" (42"), 6'6" (78"), 9' 8" (116"), 13' (156)

The picture has been through opencv undistort with a calibrated camera.

This is the function that actually performs the logic. x and y are gathered by cv2 EVENT_LBUTTONUP, and sent to this function.

Checking the lengths of the array is just to help me figure out why this isn't working, trying to generate a line to show the curve fit.

```
dist = self.firstClick-y
    self.yData.append(dist)
    
    if len(self.yData) > 4:
        print(self.poly(dist))

    if len(self.yData) == 4:

        array = np.array(self.xData)
        array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)
        
        print(self.xData)
        print(self.yData)
        
        
        array=np.append(array, [self.yData], axis=0)
        print(array)
        x = array[:,0]
        y = array[:,1]
        
        self.poly = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 2))
        poly1d = np.poly1d(self.poly)
        xp = np.linspace(-2, 20, 1)
        _ = plt.plot(x, y, '.', xp, self.poly(xp), '-', xp, self.poly(xp), '--')
        plt.ylim(0,200)
        plt.show()
```

When I run this code, my values tend to quickly go into the tens of thousands when I'm attempting to collect the measurement at 18' 11", (the lowest wire).

Any help would be appreciated, I've been up all night trying to fit this curve.

Edit:
Sorry, I should have included the code used to display and scale the image.

```
self.img = cv2.imread(imagePath, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
    self.scale_percent = 30

    self.width = int(self.img.shape[1] * self.scale_percent/100)
    self.height = int(self.img.shape[0] * self.scale_percent/100)

    dsize = (self.width, self.height)

    self.output = cv2.resize(self.img, dsize)

    img = self.output

    cv2.imshow('image', img)

    cv2.setMouseCallback('image', self.click_event)

    cv2.waitKey()
```

I just called this function to display the image and the below code to calibrate the values.

```
if self.firstClick == 0:
            self.firstClick = y
            cv2.putText(self.output, "Pole Base", (x, y), font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.imshow('image', self.output)
            
        elif self.firstClick != 0 and self.secondClick == 0:
            self.secondClick = y
            print("The difference in first and second clicks is", self.firstClick - self.secondClick)
            first = self.firstClick - self.secondClick
            inch = first/42
            foot = inch*12
            self.foot = foot
            print("One foot is currently: ", foot)
            self.firstLine = 3.5*12
            self.secondLine = 6.5*12
            self.thirdLine = 9.67*12
            self.fourthLine = 13*12

            self.xData = np.array([self.firstLine, self.secondLine, self.thirdLine, self.fourthLine])
            self.yData.append(self.firstLine)
            

            print(self.firstLine)
            print(self.secondLine)
            print(self.thirdLine)
            print(self.fourthLine)
```

Comment: did you try stepping through the code with a debugger and making sure the data at each line makes sense ? it would help to know what the values of self.xData is and what self.yData is and what do you expect the output to be.

Comment: I did. self.xData is the values in inches above, and self.yData is the number of pixels from the base of the pole to the same measured areas. I would like for them to be as close to exactly the same as possible, (within a certain margin of error, of course), but the idea is to be as accurate as possible. Once the curve has been established, I would like to use it to measure the rest of the wires and attachments on the pole.

Comment: i am not asking for their physical meaning, i am asking for the output of `print(self.xData); print(self.yData)`. as `When I run this code, my values tend to quickly go into the tens of thousands when I'm attempting to collect the measurement at 18' 11", (the lowest wire).` no one can debug this without the input values.

Comment: Completely understand, but I used the inches as the input. Sorry, I'll update with the code I used to display the image, as the pixels were really on point towards the lower end of the pole. 42 was both the length in inches and in pixels to the bottom black line.